# Validar dia - Javascript - DOM

Tags: javascript, validación

Tengo un input de tipo text con una longitud=2.

```
<input type="text" size="4" maxlength="2" name="dia" id="iddia"/>
```

Donde quiero validar que lo que se escriban sean sólo números y que si escribo un número superior o igual a 4, luego no me permita escribir más numeros debido a que el día 45-66-81 no existen, y si escribo el primer digito el 3, solo me permita los valores 30-31.

¿Por qué me permite escribir cualquier número del 1 al 99?

```
//Validar el dia.
function validacionDia(e){
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    var value = document.getElementById("iddia").value;
    var dia = value + String.fromCharCode(key);
    if (isNaN(dia) === true || dia < 1 || dia > 31) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

miformulario.dia.addEventListener("change", function(){ 
        return validacionDia(event);
    }, false);
```

¿Y para la validacion de un año/nacimiento? Aceptaria valores entre 1960 y 2010

```
//Validar el año.
function validacionAnio(e){
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    var value = document.getElementById("idanio").value;
    var anio = value + String.fromCharCode(key);
    return (anio>0 && anio<2010);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo el código, espero te sirva

```
function validaDia(value) {

  var valueInt = parseInt(value);
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    document.getElementById('iddia').value = '';
  } else if (value.length == 1 && valueInt >= 4) {
    document.getElementById('iddia').value = '0' + value;
  } else if (value.length == 2 && parseInt(value.substring(0, 1)) == 3 && (parseInt(value.substring(1, 2)) != 0 && parseInt(value.substring(1, 2)) != 1)) {
    document.getElementById('iddia').value = 3;
  }
}

function validacionAnio(val){
    if(val.length==4 && !val.match('(19[6-8][0-9]|199[0-9]|200[0-9]|2010)')){
        document.getElementById('idanio').value='';
    }
} 

document.getElementById('iddia').addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
  validaDia(this.value);
}, false);

document.getElementById('idanio').addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
  validacionAnio(this.value);
}, false);
```

He utilizado el evento onKeyUp, ya que los input de tipo texto no tienen evento onChange

Comment: No veo nada diferente en tu código validaDia a mi código validacionDia, diferente código pero mismo resultado. He cambiado el evento onchange por el "onkeyup" y tampoco me funciona.

Comment: Hay varias diferencias, la primera tu estas devolviendo true o false, que eso para el input en si no significa nada, en el callback de la funcion del evento deberias modificar el valor del input segun si te devuelve true o false no simplemente devolverlo. donde pones `return validacionDia(event);` ese parametro event no existe, deberias declararlo en la linea `miformulario.dia.addEventListener("change", function(event){ ` es rocmendable tambien parsear a entero el valor del input para que las comprobaciones sean mas correctas

Comment: Aqui te dejo un jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/3cbczw7w/2/

Comment: Error 404 jajaja. Ruta no encontrada.

Comment: Pues a mi me lo abre desde el movil amijo

Comment: Edito la pregunta...

Comment: Respuesta editada https://jsfiddle.net/3cbczw7w/3/